# Unable to alert entered value in input field

Tags: javascript

```js
function callForm() {
  var form = document.forms[0];
  var select1 = form.querySelector('input[name="pwd"]');
  var select2 = select1.value;
  alert(select2);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return callForm()">
  Password: <input type="text" name="pwd" value="defaultPassword">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After clicking on submit, I am getting the old input value always that is defaultPassword.Here I am trying to alert the entered value by the user when submit button is clicked but unable to achieve it.I think this problem is coming because of refreshing of web page, but unable to fix it.

Comment: Actually the value entered in the textbox will be shown in the alert as you can see

Comment: It works here? Maybe something interferes with your script?

Comment: In the Java Snippet, it works just fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://i.imgur.com/DFsvyTZ.png — the alert shows the edited value. (Possibly you aren't asking about the alert value, but if so your question is very unclear).

Comment: `onsubmit="return callForm()"` I would argue there is no need for the `return` and just call `callForm()` The example is working nonetheless

Comment: @FrancisLeigh — Since `callForm` implicitly returns `undefined`, that makes no difference. `onsubmit` is *already* implicitly returning `undefined`.

Comment: i don't see anything coming back as undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a form before letting javascript to manipulate it, have its cons. Try:

```js
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("btn-form-submit");
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', callForm);

function callForm() {
var form = document.forms[0];
var select1 = form.querySelector('input[name="pwd"]');
var select2 = select1.value;
alert(select2);
form.submit();
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Password: </label><input type="text" name="pwd" value="defaultPassword">
  <button id="btn-form-submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

However, your code worked perfectly on Chrome.